# Estimating price with Linear Regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm posting here because I couldn't find any solution to my problem anywhere else. Basically we are learning Linear Regression using python at school and the professor wants us to estimate the price of each ingredient in a sandwich as well as the fixed profit of each sandwich based on a csv table. So far we only messed with one X variable and one Y variable, so I'm pretty confused what should I do here? Thank you. Here is the table:

```
tomato,lettuce,cheese,pickles,palmetto,burger,corn,ham,price
0.05,1,0.05,0,0.05,0.2,0.05,0,18.4
0.05,0,0.05,0.05,0,0.2,0.05,0.05,16.15
0.05,1,0.05,0,0.05,0.4,0,0,22.15
0.05,1,0.05,0,0.05,0.2,0.05,0.05,19.4
0.05,1,0,0,0,0.2,0.05,0.05,18.4
0,0,0.05,0,0,0,0.05,0.05,11.75
0.05,1,0,0,0,0.2,0,0.05,18.15
0.05,1,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.2,0.05,0,18.65
0,0,0.05,0,0,0.2,0.05,0.05,15.75
0.05,1,0.05,0,0.05,0,0.05,0.05,15.4
0.05,1,0,0,0,0.2,0,0,17.15
0.05,1,0,0,0.05,0.2,0.05,0.05,18.9
0,1,0.05,0,0,0.2,0.05,0.05,18.75
```

Comment: Are you doing this in raw python or with a statistical package?

Comment: I can use numpy

Comment: If you can, I'd recommend using Pandas as well. It pretty much wraps numpy arrays into workable dataframes.
From there, you just have to apply multiple linear regression. If you've written a regression tool before you can definitely extend it to accommodate multiple variables.
I did something like this when I first started learning Python (developing an applied Econometric model) and since this is an important learning experience I can't really share code but I can advise that the packages you want are: Sci-kit Learn/Statsmodels for OLS; Pandas for working with data.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help!

Comment: See the EDIT below, probably there is a bit more in this assignment. I hope you still have time to do the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 9 separate variables for regression (tomato ... price), and 13 samples for each of them (the 13 lines).

So the first approach could be doing a regression for "tomato" on data points
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0
0.05
0.05
0
0.05
0.05
0.05
0
then doing another one for "lettuce" and the others, up to "price" with
18.4
16.15
22.15
19.4
18.4
11.75
18.15
18.65
15.75
15.4
17.15
18.9
18.75

Online viewer for looking at your CSV data: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-viewer-editor.htm, but Google SpreadSheet, Excel, etc. can display it nicely too.

SciPy can probably (most likely) do the task for you on vectors too (so handling the 9 variables together), but the part of having 13 samples in the 13 rows, remains.

EDIT: bad news, I was tired and have not answered the full question, sorry about that.

While it is true that you can take the first 8 columns (tomato...ham) as time series, and make individual regressions for them (which is probably the first part of this assignment), the last column (price) is expected to be estimated from the first 8.

Using the notation in Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Introduction, your `y` vector is the last column (the prices), the `X` matrix is the first 8 columns of your data (tomato...ham), extended with a column of 1-s somewhere.
Then pick an estimation method (some are listed in that page too, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Estimation_methods, but you may want to pick one you have learned about at class). The actual math is there, and NumPy can do the matrix/vector calculations. If you go for "Ordinary least squares", `numpy.linalg.lstsq` does the same (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq - you may find adding that column of 1-s familiar), so it can be used for verifying the results.

Comment: But that would be just the X values right? What would be the Y values?

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe those values are the Y-s. X would be simply 1...13 (or 0...12, if you want), so the row index.